# How to export all tables with user in Oracle 10g Enterprise edition?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, datapump

I want to take backup of all my tables and the user too in Oracle 10g Enterprise edition and then I want to import it to some other computer. The user is not system I have created another user and all my tables are in that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Oracle Datapump to perform export-import in schema(user) level.

Here are some examples.

```
expdp scott/tiger schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log
```

The above command exports `SCOTT` schema in a dump file called `SCOTT.dmp` in a directory specified using `DIRECTORY` parameter, and writes it's log in `expdpSCOTT.log` file.

You can copy this dump file to another host and use Datapump Import to import it as shown below.

```
impdp scott/tigerschemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=impdpSCOTT.log
```

**References:**

[Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200)

[Data Pump Import](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL300)

[CREATE DIRECTORY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm)